# Problem about sift mapping by using python and opencv3

Tags: python, opencv, sift

When I use SIFT to match two images, I found all points in image1 are mapped in one points in image2. I tried to change the parameter such as 0.7 or use SURF and ORB but failed. I have searched for a long time on net but no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

```
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()

kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1, None)
kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img2, None)

FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 0
index_params = dict(algorithm=FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees=5)
search_params = dict(checks=50)

flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)

matches = flann.knnMatch(des1, des2, k=2)

good = []
for m, n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.7 * n.distance:
        good.append(m)

if len(good) > MIN_MATCH_COUNT:
    src_pts = np.float32([kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
    dst_pts = np.float32([kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)

    M, mask = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RANSAC, 5)
    matchesMask = mask.ravel().tolist()

    h, w = img1.shape[:2]
    pts = np.float32([[0, 0], [0, h-1], [w-1, h-1], [w-1, 0]]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
    dst = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts, M)
    warpImg = cv2.warpPerspective(img2, np.array(M), (img2.shape[1], img2.shape[0]))
    img2 = cv2.polylines(img2, [np.int32(dst)], True, 255, 3, cv2.LINE_AA)
else:
    print("Not enough matches are found - %d/%d" % (len(good), MIN_MATCH_COUNT))
    matchesMask = None

draw_params = dict(matchColor=(0, 255, 0),  # draw matches in green color
                   singlePointColor=None,
                   matchesMask=matchesMask,  # draw only inliers
                   flags=2)

img3 = cv2.drawMatches(img1, kp1, img2, kp2, good, None, **draw_params)
```